# MySQL: Forward Engineering, error 1826

Tags: mysql, sql, database, model

I read other threads about this error, but couldn't understand how to apply it to my case. So here it goes:

I have this db model, it's my first one. Let explain what is the thinking behind it...

[image: db model]
1 user can sign up for only one plan, can have multiple files (one file can either be a photo, video, audio or note). Each file might belong to any album the user created. She can add people (not users) to her account.

I try to forward engineer this and I get this error:
[image: ERROR 1826]

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console says

> Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'IdUser_FK'

The problem here is just related to the naming: the procedure is assignin a name to your Foreing Key, `IdUser_FK` : since there are many FK in your table based on `IdUser` it fails with naming.

You can solve assigning manually the name to your FK, I suggest adding the table name, IE: `IdUser_Memoirs_FK`, `IdUser_People_FK` , and so on

Comment: Thanks Leviand! Didn't think it was that easy! :)

Comment: glad have helped :)